# How to Check if Xcode License Needs to be Accepted

Tags: xcode, macos

After upgrading to Xcode `11.1` on MacOS Catalina running some commands such as `git status` results in Xcode stating that a license must be agreed to. Obviously we could run `git status` and `grep` for some output but this seems sub-optimal.

Is there a programmatic way (using `xcodebuild` for example) to check if the Xcode license needs to be accepted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Evaluate Agreed License**

Running

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

should give something like:

```
{
    IDELastGMLicenseAgreedTo = EA1647;
    IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense = "11.3.1";
}
```

This can also be evaluated programmatically.

There are several ways to do this, one is to use a shell script, for example you could call it XcodeLicenseAccepted.sh and it will return 0 if the license for the currently installed version of Xcode is already accepted.

**Xcode version**

To get the version number of the currently installed Xcode, you can take a look at the output of:

```
xcodebuild -version
```

which should look something like this:

```
Xcode 11.3.1
Build version 11C505
```

**XcodeLicenseAccepted.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
XCODE_VERSION=`xcodebuild -version | grep '^Xcode\s' | sed -E 's/^Xcode[[:space:]]+([0-9\.]+)/\1/'`
ACCEPTED_LICENSE_VERSION=`defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode 2> /dev/null | grep IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense | cut -d '"' -f 2`

if [ "$XCODE_VERSION" = "$ACCEPTED_LICENSE_VERSION" ]
then 
    exit 0 #success
else
    exit 1
fi
```

**Swift Program**

Another possible solution would be to use a small Swift program instead, e.g.:

```
import Foundation

private var acceptedXcodeVersion: String {
    var acceptedXcodeVersion = ""
    let licensePlistPath = "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist"
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: licensePlistPath) {
        if let licenseInfo = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: licensePlistPath) {
            if let version = licenseInfo["IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense"] as? String {
                acceptedXcodeVersion = version
            }
        }
    }
    return acceptedXcodeVersion
}

private var installedXcodeVersion: String {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    process.arguments = ["-c", "xcodebuild -version"]

    let stdoutPipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = stdoutPipe
    process.launch()

    var version = ""
    let output = stdoutPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if let versionInfo = String(data: output, encoding: .utf8) {
        let lines = versionInfo.split { $0.isNewline }
        for line in lines {
            let parts = line.split { $0 == " " }
            if parts.count > 1 && parts[0] == "Xcode" {
                version = String(parts[1])
            }
        }
    }

    process.waitUntilExit()
    return version
}

exit(acceptedXcodeVersion == installedXcodeVersion ?  0 : 1)
```

**Test**

To demo the functionality of XcodeLicenseAccepted.sh one can also use a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

./XcodeLicenseAccepted.sh
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo "xcode license already accepted"
else
    echo "xcode license still needs to be accepted"
fi
```

Replace the call to `XcodeLicenseAccepted.sh` with the Swift program to test the alternative solution.

Finally a screenshot how the result looks before and after accepting the Xcode license:

[image: demo output]